# Bash: get all paths from path

Tags: bash, shell, path, traversal, dash-shell

Say I have the path `gui/site/junior/profile.py`

How do I get this?:

```
gui
gui/site
gui/site/junior
```

Bonus if you tell me how to loop through each path :D

Comment: Would it suffice to just iterate through them bottom up? For instance, loop through `gui/site/junior`, then `gui/site`, etc?

Or do you need the splitting?

Comment: No, it should start from the path closer to root..

Comment: For reference: `dirname` does the opposite (strip off the last path segment).

Answer (score 2):

You can loop with awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"}
     {  for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
           for (j=1; j<i; j++)
              printf "%s/", $j
           printf "%s\n", $i
        }
     }' <<< "gui/site/junior/profile.py"
```

See as one liner:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"}{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { for (j=1; j<i; j++) printf "%s%s", $j, OFS; printf "%s\n", $i}}' <<< "gui/site/junior/profile.py"
gui
gui/site
gui/site/junior
gui/site/junior/profile.py
```

This takes advantage of `NF`, which counts how many fields the current record has. Based on that, it loops from the first up to the last one, printing every time first up to that value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the shell's built-in splitting facilities. `IFS` specifies what to split on.

```
oldIFS=$IFS
IFS=/
set -f
set -- $path
set +f
IFS=$oldIFS
for component in "$@"; do
    echo "$component"
done
```

This could be refactored in many ways, but I want the change to `IFS` to only govern the actual splitting.

The use of `set` to split a string into positional parameters is slightly obscure, but well worth knowing.

You should properly take care to unset `IFS` if it was originally unset, but I'm skimping on that.

Comment: Very interesting approach. I like the way you make use of IFS and `set` to accomplish this. Also it allows you to work with each one of the components. In case the OP wants to do something with each block, this is more useful than my answer.

Comment: You should add `set -f` to disable pathname expansion of the unquoted `$path`, and reset it when you're done.

Comment: @user2719058 Thanks, incorporated

Answer (score 2):

a dash answer:

```
path="gui/site with spaces/junior/profile.py"
oldIFS=$IFS
IFS=/
set -- $(dirname "$path")
IFS=$oldIFS
accumulated=""
for dir in "$@"; do 
  accumulated="${accumulated}${dir}/"
  echo "$accumulated"
done
```

```
gui/
gui/site with spaces/
gui/site with spaces/junior/
```

Comment: Hmmm, this is suspiciously similar to mine?

Comment: And both buggy with respect to globbing characters in the pathname.

Comment: can always throw in a `set -f` to handle that

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately, the inherent elegance of the `for ...` loop is destroyed by all that boilerplate modifying and resetting `IFS` and `set -f`. I have recently thought about ways to solve, in shell, the simple problem of iterating over tokens separated by some delimiter character, and coulnd't find a truely elegant method.

Answer (score 1):

Perl variant:

```
perl -F/ -nlE 'say join("/",@F[0..$_])||"/"for(0..$#F-1)' <<< "gui/site with spaces/junior/profile.py"
```

produces

```
gui
gui/site with spaces
gui/site with spaces/junior
```

if you have NULL separates pathnames, you can add `0` to arguments:

```
perl -F/ -0nlE 'say join("/",@F[0..$_])||"/"for(0..$#F-1)'
          ^
```

e.g from

```
printf "/some/path/name/here/file.py\0" |  perl -F/ -nlE 'say join("/",@F[0..$_])||"/"for(0..$#F-1)'
#                                   ^^
```

produces

```
/
/some
/some/path
/some/path/name
/some/path/name/here
```

For iterating over the paths, you can use the next:

```
origpath="some/long/path/here/py.py"

do_something() {
        local path="$1"
        #add here what you need to do with the partial path
        echo "Do something here with the ==$path=="
}

while read -r part
do
        do_something "$part"
done < <(perl -F/ -nlE 'say join("/",@F[0..$_])||"/"for(0..$#F-1)' <<< "$origpath")
```

it produces:

```
Do something here with the ==some==
Do something here with the ==some/long==
Do something here with the ==some/long/path==
Do something here with the ==some/long/path/here==
```