# Manipulate the output of echo $PATH

Tags: shell

With `echo $PATH` I get this:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

And what I would like is to get these in the following format:

```
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
...
```

What I tried to do:

```
i=1;
for dir in `echo $PATH|cut -d ':' -f $i`
do
    echo $dir
    i=`expr $i + 1`
done
```

But it doesn't work. Could someone help me with an answer?

Comment: Frequently asked, e.g., [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25447010/bash-get-all-paths-from-path/25448507) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273909/how-do-i-manipulate-path-elements-in-shell-scripts/373476).

Comment: Then why has no one marked it a duplicate as such?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tr` to the rescue:

```
echo "$PATH" | tr : '\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
old_IFS=$IFS
IFS=:
set -- $PATH
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    echo $1;
    shift;
done
IFS=$old_IFS
```

Comment: Did you mean `$old_IFS` in the last line? Also this approach should have failed had the user performed some other action instead of just echoing `$1`,

Answer (score 0):

You should do this :

```
i=0
echo "$PATH" | awk 'BEGIN{RS=":"}{printf "%s\0",$0}'| while read -rd '' line
do
echo "$line"; # or do something else with it?
i=`expr $i + 1`
done
```

This will take care of non-standard folders  in the path variable like 
`/usr/local folder` &`/usr/new/continued/in/next/line
folder` and so on.

You could also use `tr` instead of `awk` but replace `\n` with `\0` like below :

```
echo "$PATH" | tr : '\0' | while ...
```

Comment: @Biffen Not `bashism` coz this [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) says it is  supported at least in bash, ksh, or zs. Good point anyway. I will edit the answer.

Comment: @Biffen : Appreciate the time, Edited :D